# Using wvdial in /etc/network/interfaces to enable automatic connection with usb 3g dongle

Tags: debian-squeeze, wvdial

I have wvdial working from the command line in a debian squeeze 32 bit install.

Googling around revealed several suggestions to simply use

auto ppp0
iface ppp0 inet wvdial

However, upon reboot I get the error:

startpar: service(s) returned failure: wvdial ... failed!

I have also had zero luck getting wvdial to run from an init.d script. Any suggestions?

Comment: I have also tried getting wvdial to automatically start by setting a cron job for @reboot. Does not work, no errors thrown that I can see.

Comment: Can you start wvdial from command line? Does it need an extra argument for the profile name? Are you using the exact same command in the init script?